# Android parse URL inside WebPage

Tags: android, parsing, url

I have have a WebView that show me a webpage that include an URL that contains a RSS feed, how can i store the URL before the page is loaded?

Example page:

This page is your personal news channel

URL of RSS channel:
http://domain.com/news/feed.php?user_id=150&hash=7cde58a3f234929385068d3e64c13e

%%%%%EDIT CODE TO ENTER THE PAGE%%%%

```
 public class ilias extends Activity {

 WebView webView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://www.ilias.de/docu/login.php?client_id=docu");
        List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "stacked")); //this username 
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "overflow"));//works


  try {
   UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
         request.setEntity(entity);

         HttpResponse response= httpClient.execute(request);

   bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
   StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
   String line = "";
   String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
   while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator); 
   }
   bufferedReader.close();

   Toast.makeText(ilias.this, 
     "Finished", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   String webData = stringBuffer.toString();

   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
   webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.ilias.de/docu/",webData,"text/html","UTF-8","about:blank");
   String postData = "username=stacked&password=overflow";
   String url = "http://www.ilias.de/docu/login.php?client_id=docu";

  webView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64"));

  webView.loadUrl("http://www.ilias.de/docu/ilias.php?col_side=left&block_type=pdnews&cmd=showFeedUrl&cmdClass=ilpdnewsblockgui&cmdNode=i7:db:le&baseClass=ilPersonalDesktopGUI");

  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(ilias.this, 
     e.toString(), 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(ilias.this, 
     e.toString(), 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }finally{
   if (bufferedReader != null){
    try {
     bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }

    }
}
```

Comment: So the webpage includes the url and not the app itself, or the code?

Comment: the url is on the webpage. ı need to parse it and then use it in my app

Comment: You need to use a HTML parser such as JSOUP and parse the url text using the tag.

Comment: What is the webpage you are trying to parse? I need the link to show you how to do it.

Comment: or the css tag or attribute..like div class or div id.

Comment: you have to log in http://ilias.de/docu/login.php with user "stacked" pass "overflow" and then click on orange RSS button, there you will see the URL i want

Comment: edit with code to enter the page with URL FEED

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create an own WebViewClient. Then you can save the url before it get called/shown:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                    // save url here

        // false = open all urls with the embedded browser 
        return false;
    }
}
```

now add your Webview client to the webview:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Comment: sry i think i didnt explain correctly. i already have my webviewclient that load the webpage that include the url as html link

Comment: My code should be called everytime a link inside your webview is clicked. Isn't that what you want? Isn't the link as a normal <a href element in the website? If so, you could try a regular expression on the content...

Comment: i dont want to click the link, i just want to parse when webpage loads.